Partial sums of Möbius function and Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex for closed sets of a topology on the prime powers?
In A cell complex in number theory by Anders Björner, 2011 a number theoretic cell complex is described which has the property that the Euler characteristic is related to the Mertens function:
$$M(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)$$
In the simplicial complex I am considering we might have:
Let $p$ be a prime. Then my question is , if it is true, that:
$$-1+\sum_{1\le k \le n}\mu(pk) =^? \chi(n,p)$$
where $\chi(n,p)$ denotes the Euler characteristic of the constructed simplicial complex below: $\Delta_{n,p}$.
For this I want to first define a topological space on the prime powers:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ be a natural number, which can be $=0$. We associate to this number the set:
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
    S(n):=\{p^k : 1 \le k \le v_p(n), p\mid n , p \text{ is prime}\}
\end{equation}
For instance we have $S(0)=\hat{\mathbb{P}}={}$the set of all prime powers ($1$ is not counted as a prime power). And $S(1) = \emptyset$.
The sets $S(n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$  are the closed sets of a topology on the set of prime powers $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$, since we have:
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
    S(m) \cap S(n)=S(\gcd(m,n)) \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}_0,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
    S(m) \cup S(n)=S(\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}) \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}_0,
\end{equation}
and by Bézout's theorem the $\gcd$ of an infinite number of natural numbers can be defined:
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
    \bigcap_{i\in I} S(n_i) = S(\gcd(\{ n_i : i\in I\})).
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}\label{eq5}
    m = n \iff S(m) = S(n) \iff O(m) = O(n), 
\end{equation}
where the open sets are defined as $O(n):=\hat{\mathbb{P}}-S(n)$.
So this allows us to think about natural numbers as the closed sets of a topological space on the prime powers. Each closed set has finitely many points, consisting of the prime power divisors of $n$.
Let $p$ be a prime.
The simplicial complex $\Delta_{n,p}$ is defined as:
$$\Delta_{n,p}:=\{T : T \subset S(k), 1 \le k \le n, k \not\equiv 0 \mod(p) \}$$
The simplicial complex can be defined for each finite set of numbers $n_1,\cdots,n_r$:
$$\Delta(n_1,\cdots,n_r) := \{ T: T \subset S(n_k) , 1 \le k \le r \}$$
Here is some code for $p=17$ as an example:
def S(n):
    ll = []
    for p in prime_divisors(n):
        ll.extend([(p**k) for k in range(1,valuation(n,p)+1)])
    return sorted(ll)


def simplicial_complex(nums):
    for a in nums:
        for b in nums:
            if not gcd(a,b) in nums:
                return None            
    sns = [S(num) for num in nums]
    # Hinzufügen von 0-Simplexen (Eckpunkten)
    cmplex = SimplicialComplex(sns)
    return cmplex    

pp = []

for a in range(1,80):
    n = a
    M = 17
    rr = list([x for x in range(1,n+1) if x%M!=0])
    cmplex = simplicial_complex(rr)
    pp.append((n,(cmplex.euler_characteristic())))
    print(pp[-1][1],-moebius(M)+sum([moebius(M*x) for x in range(1,n+1)]))   
line(pp).show()    

Output data:
0 0
1 1
2 2
2 2
3 3
2 2
3 3
3 3
3 3
2 2
3 3
3 3
4 4
3 3
2 2
2 2
2 2
2 2
3 3
3 3
2 2
1 1
2 2
2 2
2 2
1 1
1 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
4 4
3 3
3 3
2 2
2 2
3 3
2 2
1 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
4 4
4 4
3 3
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
5 5
5 5
4 4
4 4
3 3
2 2
3 3
3 3
4 4
3 3
3 3
3 3
2 2
3 3
4 4
4 4
3 3
4 4
5 5
5 5
6 6
5 5
5 5
5 5
4 4
5 5
6 6


Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952867/euler-characteristic-and-the-mertens-function
